# accessing tags from different classes - cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tags, box2d-iphone

This might sound quite straightforward. How can tags from one class accessed in another in cocos2d. I plan to use these tags to create a contact listener between a rope (rope class made of revolute joints) and a sprite (sprite class). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the tag property of the CCNode class ?

Comment: yes. both rope and sprite classes inherit from NSObject and are initialized in the parentLayer (HelloWorldLayer.mm).

Answer (score 2):

well, you can always retrieve an object that derives from CCNode as follows:

```
MyClass *anObject=(MyClass*) [theContainerObject getChildByTag:theObjectTagToRetrieve];
```

note that MyClass must also derive from CCNode (you could not have added it in the first place as a child of another CCNode derivative. Luck with that, it seems like a lot of properties to expose in HelloWorldLayer. Maybe another approach would be to add object getter methods in HelloWorldLayer that you could use elsewhere, ie hide your implementation details but provide the functionality.

Comment: I am working on it. But I think the object getter methods approach would be better. How should I go about it?